# overflow not flowing over enough

Tags: css, html, overflow

I've got a piece of code consisting of styled images that need to fit within a fixed sized div. If it does not, it should flow over. However, the floated element that does not fit, flows over as it should but touches the other elements and places itself over one of their shadows.

It's best to explain using an example: http://jsfiddle.net/wjw83/10/

The 7th image (barely visible) should vanish entirely or move further down where it moves out of the visible area. Can anyone help me accomplish this?

Thank you.

*EDIT*

Being out of ideas and on the verge of raging, I've started pasting random attributes and eventually was successful.

Solved: http://jsfiddle.net/wjw83/13/

All I had to was add "margin-bottom: 20px;" to the image class. Since it's the same value as the shadow, it leaves the shadow intact while completely removing the clipped element. Whoohoo!

Comment: I was about to add the answer when I noticed you the edit to your question.

Comment: Please post the solution you found as an answer and accept it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being out of ideas and on the verge of raging, I've started pasting random attributes and eventually was successful.

Solved: http://jsfiddle.net/wjw83/13/

All I had to was add "margin-bottom: 20px;" to the image class. Since it's the same value as the shadow, it leaves the shadow intact while completely removing the clipped element. Whoohoo!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.main{
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 870px;
    height: 140px; /* Reduced height */
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**Live demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wjw83/12/)**

Comment: Thanks but it cuts off a bit of the bottom shadow effect of the other images.